# How can i append some data in tail function written in python

Tags: python, linux

I copied this python function which reads last n lines from file

```
def tail(self, f, window=20 ):
    BUFSIZ = 1024
    f.seek(0, 2)
    bytes = f.tell()
    size = window
    block = -1
    data = []
    while size > 0 and bytes > 0:
        if (bytes - BUFSIZ > 0):
            # Seek back one whole BUFSIZ
            f.seek(block*BUFSIZ, 2)
            # read BUFFER
            data.append(f.read(BUFSIZ))
        else:
            # file too small, start from begining
            f.seek(0,0)
            # only read what was not read
            data.append(f.read(bytes))
        linesFound = data[-1].count('\n')
        size -= linesFound
        bytes -= BUFSIZ
        block -= 1
    return '\n'.join(''.join(data).splitlines()[-window:])
```

Now what i want is, if the line contains word "error" then i need to `append` and `prepend` `\n` to the word `error` so that my line with error is separatred  from the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appends and prepends `'\n'` to all *lines* containing the string `'error'`:

```
def segregate(lines, word):
    for line in lines:
        if word in line:
            yield '\n'+line+'\n'
        else:
            yield line
```

which you can hook up to `tail` like this:

```
def tail(f, window=20):
    ...
    return '\n'.join(segregate(''.join(data).splitlines()[-window:], 'error'))
```

---

If instead you wish to append and prepend `'\n'` to just the string `'error'`, then you could instead use `re.sub`:

```
import re
def tail(f, window=20):
    ...
    return '\n'.join(re.sub(r'error', '\nerror\n', ''.join(data)).splitlines()[-window:])
```

Comment: This is appeding at the end of line not after the word. also this don't catch the word if that is the substring like `Fielderror`